# 1-Wire sensor to high temperature about 200 C

Tags: temperature

I'm using 1-wire network temperatures in the furnishing and now
I would like to measure the solar thermal collector in the upper end of the temperature of 1-wire sensor attached to the network. But the Dallas DS1820 series runs for 125 C. What to do?

Answer (score 3):

I don't think any of the integrated semiconductor digital temperature sensors work above 150°C. Certainly nothing as high as 200°C.

"About 200°C" suggests you may need marginally higher. Realistically, this is going to require a thermocouple or RTD to measure.

You could use one of these and create a bridge to 1-Wire to fit in with your network.

I have seen a [DS2760 Li Battery Monitor](https://solarbotics.com/product/35020/) used for this before, but it can only read up to 127°C.

You may need to build something custom.